# Standardization in combination with scaling

Tags: machine-learning, training, preprocessing, normalization, feature-scaling

Would it be ok to standardize all the features that exhibit normal distribution (with `StandardScaler`) and then re-scale all the features in the range 0-1 (with `MinMaxScaler`). So far I've only seen people doing one OR the other, but not in combination. Why is that?

Also, is the Shapiro Wilk Test a good way to test if standardization is advisable? Should all features exhibit a normal distribution or are you allowed to transform only the ones that do have it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing both on a given feature is redundant, and equivalent to doing whichever you do last; they are both linear transformations.

`StandardScaler` doesn't require normally distributed data to be useful.  It just centers and scales each feature so that it has mean zero and standard deviation 1; that's potentially useful no matter the distribution.  See [this stats.SE answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/453216/232706).

As to which is better, I don't know that there's a right answer.  One of the sklearn core devs answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59447032/10495893), but it leaves a lot open.

Answer (score 1):

Once you `standardize` the data, the data falls in the range `-3.14` to `+3.14` in `99.99%` of the cases(`6 Sigma`). The main reason for standardizing the data is achieved as the data falls in a short range and the `algorithm can converge faster`. Applying `normalization` on top of it would further scale down the data to `-1 to +1`. So, in regular practise `one of them` is applied based on the scenario. As in the real data, data will be having outliers and the distributon might not be Gaussian, there are other scaling techniques(`Robust Scaler` can efficiently deal even we have outliers in the data. `Quantile transformer Scaler` also handles when there are outliers which under the hood uses a `CDF` to transform the data using that function.)